# Getting image from xcassets with pixate

Tags: ios, pixate, xcasset

I am using `xcassets` to store my images, but I am having some issues to get images using `pixate`.
If the image is outside `xcassets` I can use something like `background-image: url(image.png);` without any issue but this doesn't work with `xcassets`.

Any ideas?

Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Freestyle is adding a new asset:// scheme in 2.1.2 which will allow for urls like this:

`background-image: url(asset://image)`.